# Why can't Leads or Users be Masters in a Master-Detail relationship

Tags: master-detail

I ask this both out of curiosity, and if I wanted to create an object that I wanted to act as a child to one of those objects I would have a better idea how I could do that.  Let's say for example that I wanted to save data unique to a lead that I collected at a kiosk that doesn't fit in the standard lead object ... creating a child object to hold that information would make sense, but I can't.

Comment: Please check this .. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/no-master-detail-relationship-in-which-the-user-or-lead-objects-are-the-master

Comment: The answer is probably `because Salesforce says so`. Is there a reason why a lookup relationship wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Just would be nice to do roll-up summaries on the leads based on the information collected at the kiosk.

Comment: I think the same applies for product object also.

Comment: You could use Andrew Fawcett's [declarative rollup summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to accomplish that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No master-detail relationship in which the User or Lead objects are the master?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/no-master-detail-relationship-in-which-the-user-or-lead-objects-are-the-master)

Answer (score 7):

This currently is not a functionality in Salesforce. Check out the below excerpt from the [Relationships Among Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm) developer page.

> You can define master-detail relationships between custom objects or between a custom object and a standard object. However, the standard object cannot be on the detail side of a relationship with a custom object. **In addition, you cannot create a master-detail relationship in which the User or Lead objects are the master.**

There is an idea out on the community if you would like to vote for it. [Ability to create Master-Detail relationships from Custom Objects to Leads](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq50)

Comment: This is the information I was too lazy/slow to look up. +1 from me.

Comment: The documentation link is helpful, but this does not answer the ***why***, which really is the question here. It seems there is not much to answer, though. Except "because Salesforce says so". See the answer [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/no-master-detail-relationship-in-which-the-user-or-lead-objects-are-the-master) for some logical guesses.